# Python- requests: website won't accept request to log in

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am using python requests to login to a website, but it will not accept my request.

I have looked for hidden inputs in the source code of the website but could not find any, and I have heard that it could be something to do with adding headers, but I don't know how to find the headers or how to add them to my code.

```
session = requests.session()

login_data = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'S75hu6eF1FV6axGK8ffV5JC7mYw8Z3AbviU453U0rOQPYPu7iiBCVxRnV2XywfVh',
    'username': '<my_username>',
    'password': '<my_password>',
    'next': '/course/2021573/french-1-145/garden/speed_review/?source_element=ms_mode&source_screen=eos_ms'
}

session.get(url)

r = session.post('https://www.memrise.com/course/2021573/french-1-145/garden/speed_review/?source_element=ms_mode&source_screen=eos_ms/login.py', login_data)

if r.status_code == 200:
    res = session.get(url)
    print('YES!!!')
else:
    print('NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO')
```

I would expect for the status code to be 200, but it is not- I don't know what the status code is when it doesn't accept the request. Any help would be appreciated in solving this problem.

Comment: what status code it is giving?

Comment: It is the 403 forbidden error- I have checked that there are no url errors in the code

Comment: try to login through postman and check which are needed headers for this url.

Comment: try `robobrowser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**www.memrise.com** has CSRF-Token method in it's login, so you have to find CSRF-Token from login page using BeautifulSoup and use headers.

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.memrise.com/login/'
session = requests.session()

response = session.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
csrf_token = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'}).get('value')

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.memrise.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.memrise.com/login/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

login_data = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token,
    'username': '<my_username>',
    'password': '<my_password>',
    'next': '/course/2021573/french-1-145/garden/speed_review/?source_element=ms_mode&source_screen=eos_ms'
}

r = session.post(url, login_data, headers=headers)

if r.status_code == 200:
    res = session.get(url)
    print('YES!!!')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: You beat me to it :) I was gonna ask OP "do you know how CSRF tokens work?"

Comment: Nah, sorry- it is still coming up with the 403 error code when I try out the code above.

Comment: @jack, I missed headers while making request. Now it is working.